# How do I resolve "Failed to create process" in Anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, data-science

I downloaded Anaconda 3.6, but when I tried "conda update conda" or tried opening jupyter notebook, it shows Failed to create process. Please help!

Comment: please try uninstall the Anaconda 3.6 and reinstall the latest Anaconda so that you no need to do the conda upate. This should solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled 64-bit software, removed shortcuts, installed 32-bit software and ran below command at the Anaconda prompt.

(base) PS C:\anaconda3\Scripts> conda install -c anaconda anaconda-navigator

Once updates done, navigator client opened with no issues.